# Android putJSON is not returning anything

Tags: android

The following code is returning nothing .... blank. I am trying to insert a record to db.

```
public String inserComment(String url, String commentby, String commenton, String      commenttext, String taskid)
{
        String result = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
              jsonObject.put("CommentBy", commentby);
              jsonObject.put("CommentOn", commenton);
              jsonObject.put("CommentText", commenttext);
              jsonObject.put("TaskID", taskid);

          result = HttpHelper.postJSONforStringResult(url, jsonObject);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
          Log.e("DataUploader", "JSONException:" + e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e("DataUploader", "IOException:" + e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}


public static String postJSONforStringResult(String url, JSONObject json)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

      HttpResponse response = postJSON(url, json);

      int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
      String result = (statusCode == 201 || statusCode == 200) ? EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()) : "StatusCode=" + statusCode;
      return result;
 }
```

I don't know why indetation is not working today. So sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the server you're posting to is actually returning anything? Just because you get a good status code back doesn't necessarily mean that the server actually put any content in the response.